# Disable specific dates on p:calendar / p:datePicker

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

Is it possible to disable specific dates (for example: 15th May or 23rd June) on the PrimeFaces 3.5 `<p:calendar>` component? There is min and max, but I need to disable specific dates like public holidays **using el expressions so I can use dynamic dates.**

Using Hieu's answer, make sure the dates you disable have NO leading zeros in front (eg. '03/03/2013' should be '3/3/2013').

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: write a javascript function to disable a list of dates

```
var disabledDays = ["5-15-2013", "6-23-2013"];
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
```

Step 2: use `beforeShowDay` attribute of Primefaces datepicker

```
<p:calendar id="pfdate" navigator="true" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" 
      value="#{day}" beforeShowDay="disableAllTheseDays" showOn="button"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this should work. However, is it possible to import these disabled dates into the javascript function dynamically? I will retrieve them from a database.

Comment: It's possible, Apoorv. You can use JSF EL to load dynamic disabledDays

Comment: Thanks Hieu. I would replace the first line with, `var disabledDays = #{bean.randomDateList}`? Perissf, how can i use a custom validator or an Ajax event handler with this case?

Comment: Yes, it worked. However, i tried to use JSF EL and it didn't work. I used `#{bean.dateString}` and dateString is a type of string.

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed the issue by just using a string that is in the format of a javascript array (eg. "['12/12/12', '3/3/12']").

Comment: How can I convert from java String array to javascript in the p:calendar format?

Answer (score 1):

To disable all friday days, i have used the beforeShowDay attribute on the p:calendar , the code beloow explains this :

```
<p:calendar ..... mask="true" locale="fr" beforeShowDay="fridaysDisabled" .... required="true" maxdate="new Date();"/>
```

AND the JavaScript function :

```
function fridaysDisabled(date)
{
  var day = date.getDay();
  return [day != 5, '']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable an array of dates, follow these steps:

Create a string object that contains all the dates:

```
festivosArray = "[";
for(CalendarioDao dia : festivos){
    festivosArray += "'" + dia.getFecha() + "',";
}
festivosArray += "]";
```

Create a JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deshabFest(date) {
    var disabledDays = #{calendarioView.festivosArray};

    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
    return [disabledDays.indexOf(string) == -1, '']
}
</script>
```

Use the `beforeshowday` attribute to call the function

```
<p:calendar mode="inline" locale="es" value="#{calendarioView.fechaFestivo}" id="calendarioFestivo" widgetVar="calendarioFestivo" beforeShowDay="deshabFest" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: [`p:calendar` is deprecated since PrimeFaces 10](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0). So if you are on PrimeFaces 10 or higher, it's best to migrate to `p:datePicker`. With `p:datePicker`, although there are others ways, you can use lazy metadata to add disabled dates. I think this is the most convenient way when the dates you have to disable are many and dynamic. Quick example on how to setup the lazy metadata model:

```java
private final DateMetadataModel modelLazy;

public MyBean() {
    DefaultDateMetadata metadataDisabled = DefaultDateMetadata.builder().disabled(true).build();
    modelLazy = new LazyDateMetadataModel() {
        @Override
        public void loadDateMetadata(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
            add(localDateToDisable, metadataDisabled);
        }
    };
}
```

See the showcase for a demo: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/metadata.xhtml