# Primefaces Calendar - disabling specific dates using EL

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, calendar, el

so from my previous question, [Disable specific dates on p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar), i know that i can disable specific dates using Javascript like this:

```
  var disabledDays = ["5-15-2013", "6-23-2013"];
  function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
```

with:

```
<p:calendar id="pfdate" navigator="true" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" 
      value="#{day}" BeforeShowDay="disableAllTheseDays" showOn="button"/>
```

**However, my question is that how can i store dates in `disabledDays` array using EL expressions?** I need to do this because the dates that i need to disable varies. Disabling dates needs to be dynamic. If i can't do this with EL expressions, is there anyways to use an array that will have dynamic data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is just converting the value in a bean (`["5-15-2013", "6-23-2013"]`), and put it directly in the Javascript code:

```
var disabledDays = #{myBean.disabledDays};
```

It's not the cleanest one, but the easiest. Another possibility is just having the list of strings in the bean and use `<ui:repeat>` to print it as a comma separated list.

Comment: disabledDays should type String Array?

Comment: In the first case, it has to be just a string. Then, in the getter of the bean you format the disabled dates to build the string: `"['5-15-2013', '6-23-2013']"`.