# Jquery Primefaces Calendar - Allowing past disabled months to be seen

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, primefaces, calendar

I am using the jquery calendar through primefaces and I need to show previous and future months that have all their dates disabled.

This is my code for the calendar (2nd July to 28th July are enabled) :

```
<p:calendar id="endDate" mode="inline" mindate="02/07/2013" maxdate="28/07/2013" value="#{detentionForm.punishment.endDate}" />
```

In this situation, the user can only see July (they can't navigate to other months), however I need to let the user navigate to previous and future months regardless of those months having all their dates disabled. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar