# Disable specific days in p:calendar?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I am working on `Primefaces` in JSF , i am just trying to disable all sundays in calendar,

How can i do it,,

- As i referred sites, i got a point we can achieve it using `beforeShowDay` but i don't know how to use it.
- [Primefaces user guide](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/p-calendar.pdf) page 10 explains it, but i don't understand what they trying to say.

  ```
  <p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}" beforeShowDay="tuesdaysAndFridaysOnly" />

  function tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled(date)
  {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 2 && day != 5), '']
  }
  ```

In above code they are calling the function `tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled` from `beforeShowDay` but my question is

- They are calling the function name as `tuesdaysAndFridaysOnly` but how it will affect the function `tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled`

And it not working too.. How to achieve it and what is happening there..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable specific dates on p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error in the Primefaces documentation. They function `tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled` should be called instead of `tuesdaysAndFridaysOnly`, which is a javascript function you can call to customize the date.

So the correct source code would look like

```
<p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}" beforeShowDay="tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled" />
```

And within the function `tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled` you can do whatever you want with the provided parameter date. In this case the tuesdays (`2`) and fridays (`5`) are disabled.

```
function tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled(date)
{
  var day = date.getDay();
  return [(day != 2 && day != 5), '']
}
```

The documentation states:

> The function returns an array with two values, first one is flag to
>   indicate if date would be displayed as enabled and second parameter is
>   the optional style class to add to date cell.

As you can see. If the `date` is a tuesday or friday, the first parameter in the returned array is `false`, which means that these days won't be selected within the `p:calendar`.

**Update:**
You can find a similar question here: [Disable specific dates on p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar?rq=1).

Comment: Nice i got it..but the thing is the script function is not getting called. and date picker is also not getting pop-up..

Comment: Check the naming of the function provided in `p:calendar` and the javascript function. It necessary do a page refresh and clear your cache. Do you see any warnings/errors in the browser-console (Use the Developer Tools/Firebug to see the console). Why the calendar does not pop up is another question, create a separate one please.