# how to disable inbetween days of the month in p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

Is it possible to disable excluding first date and last date of the month? For example: current date: `3-11-2016`, so `1-11-2016 and 30-11-2016` alone enable this `(1-11-2016 and 30-11-2016)` will be calculate by dynamic month. So, I am trying to bring first date and last date enable other than this all should be disabled.

Comment: do you want to enable just the month of the current date, is that what you need??

Comment: For each month I need to enable first day and last day alone @ Billy Hope

Comment: this may help you : this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar

Answer (score 1):

If you need to enable only the month of the current date, you have to set dynamically two dates (min and max) from the managed bean, using the java class Calendar that provides methods to manipulate dates, you can use the following lines:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
minDate = cal.getTime();
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 59, 59);
maxDate = cal.getTime();
```

then you set this two date to define a range in the calendar:

```
<p:calendar mindate="#{calendarController.minDate}" 
            maxdate="#{calendarController.maxDate}" 
            ......>
</p:calendar>
```

to disable the rest of the month, leaving only 01st and 30th day take a look at this: [Disable specific dates on p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559559/disable-specific-dates-on-pcalendar)

Answer (score -2):

```
try {
        String mindateString="1/11/2016";
        String maxdateString="30/11/2016";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        setMindate(format.parse(mindateString));
        setMaxdate(format.parse(maxdateString));

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
primefaces calendar...
<p:calendar maxdate="#{welcomeController.maxdate}" 
            mindate="#{welcomeController.mindate}" size="10"
            readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
</p:calendar>
```

[image]